# mySQL full outer join with a inner join?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure of the best way to go about this or even if it’s possible. Let’s say I have 4 tables, categories, documents, other_documents, more_documents only documents have a category the others don’t. I'm using MySQL and PHP. I understand a full outer join is not an option in mysql and must be worked around using left and right joins.

I can get all the documents and inner join the categories on them where the id’s match, great!

Now I have the above data set I also want other_documents and more_documents ‘adding’ to the bottom of the above results sets and null filling in where the categories don’t line up.

Say in the more_documents table there is a unique column that the documents and other_documents tables do not have. An example, phil and dave submit data into the documents and other_documents tables and jon only submits data into the more_documents table so the results would read:

Id  -   Title    -      publisher  -    category       -   unique more_documents  column

1     -    doc1      -      dave        -     global        -    null

2    -   doc2    -      phil      -     hr         -       null

3    -   doc3     -     dave       -    operations      -  null

4   -    doc4      -    dave      -     global        -    null

5    -   doc5       -   jon       -     global     -       12345

6   -    doc6   -       jon     -       hr        -        12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to structure the query with a "driver" subquery:

```
select driver.Id, driver.Title, driver.publisher, c.category
from ((select id, categoryId, Title, publisher
       from documents
      ) union
      (select id, NULL, Title, publisher
       from more_documents
      ) union
      (select id, NULL, Title, publisher
       from other_documents
      )
     ) driver left outer join
     category c
     on driver.category_id = c.categoryId
```

Note that `union` is used in the `driver` subquery because it removes duplicates.

You may need additional joins back to the document tables to pick up fields that are only in one table.

Comment: Hi Gordon thanks for the helpful answer I'm now close to what I need, but I;m failing to see what the c.category in the SELECT part of this statement is actually doing in the query? Can you clarify its role? Thank You

Comment: @twigg . . . "Category" is in the sample data in the question.